# DELETE FROM WHERE IN, but with 2 fields and no Id

Tags: sql, sql-server, delete-row, sql-delete

I have this table:

```
StudentId | ConfigurationTypeId
1         | 1
1         | 2
1         | 3
2         | 1
2         | 2
```

I want to delete all records from this table when `ConfigurationTypeId = 3`

So I made this query:

```
DELETE FROM [StudentConfigurationType] WHERE StudentId IN
  (SELECT StudentId FROM [StudentConfigurationType] SCT 
  INNER JOIN [Student] S ON S.Id = SCT.StudentId
  WHERE SCT.ConfigurationTypeId = 3 AND S.RegisteredDate < '2014-09-18')
```

But, because this table have no Id, the StudentId comes in, and it's removing all the records from the table.
How can make something like this:

```
DELETE FROM [StudentConfigurationType] WHERE StudentId AND ConfigurationTypeId IN
  (SELECT StudentId, ConfigurationTypeId FROM [StudentConfigurationType] SCT
  INNER JOIN [Student] S ON S.Id = SCT.StudentId
  WHERE SCT.ConfigurationTypeId = 3 AND S.RegisteredDate < '2014-09-18')
```

Comment: which database backend? In SQl Server I woudl use a join rather than where in for this. But teh strucrture for that type of query is differnt for other backends. Never post a SQl question without specifying the datbase backend. It makes a differnce to the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try this:

```
DELETE FROM [StudentConfigurationType] WHERE (StudentId, ConfigurationTypeId) IN
  (SELECT StudentId, ConfigurationTypeId FROM [StudentConfigurationType] SCT
  INNER JOIN [Student] S ON S.Id = SCT.StudentId
  WHERE SCT.ConfigurationTypeId = 3 AND S.RegisteredDate < '2014-09-18');
```

Or this:

```
DELETE FROM [StudentConfigurationType] 
WHERE StudentId IN (SELECT StudentId 
                      FROM [StudentConfigurationType] SCT
                           INNER JOIN [Student] S ON S.Id = SCT.StudentId
                      WHERE S.RegisteredDate < '2014-09-18')
 AND ConfigurationTypeId = 3;
```

Or this:

```
DELETE FROM [StudentConfigurationType] st
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Student] S WHERE S.Id = ST.StudentId AND S.RegisteredDate < '2014-09-18')
 AND ConfigurationTypeId = 3;
```

Comment: First doesn't work. "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected" is being pointed out at StudentId in the first line

Comment: @Matheus Lima the first should work in Oracle. That's why I gave different queries. What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Matheus Lima I'd recommend the query with an EXISTS. I've updated my answer too.

Comment: @Matheus: First, always add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, instead of wasting people's time. ("Your solution doesn't work." "It's for Oracle" "Oh. Well I'm not using Oracle." "Well, you should have said that by adding a tag."). Second, never change the requirements or conditions of a question once you've received an answer based on the old requirements. It makes people who answered you look foolish (because the answer is now wrong or incomplete), wastes their time, and can cost them reputation if they're downvoted for that wrong or incomplete answer.

Comment: @KenWhite you're absolutely wright. Not going to happen again.